# How do I get the current user from the queryset filter method?

Tags: django

I want to show a list of store information for the current user

**model.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class Store(models.Model):
    u_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    business_number = models.IntegerField()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
current_user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, 
                                                  default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

class Meta:
    model = Store
    fields = ('url', 'id', 'u_id', 'store_name', 'business_number', 'title', 'content', 'image', 'current_user')
```

**views.py**

```
class MyStoreDetailView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    queryset = models.Store.objects.filter(u_id=??????) # how to get current user
    serializer_class = serializers.StoreSerializer
```

I've tried

1. (u_id=request.user.id) = > request not available

2.

```
class MyStoreDetailView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def current_user(self):
        return self.request.user.id
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    queryset = models.Store.objects.filter(u_id=current_user()) 
    serializer_class = serializers.StoreSerializer
```

2-> TypeError: current_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: can you try like this ..(u_id=request.user)

Comment: Thank you for answer
I have already tried but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your queryset in your ApiView `get_queryset` method.

**views.py**

```py
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class MyStoreDetailView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    queryset = models.Store.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StoreSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(u_id=self.request.user)
```

This will restrict access to `user's` Store.

I cannot help you any further without business logic, but you might want to handle cases where:

- user is not authenticated
- user is superuser (if you use this endpoint in some admin)

Comment: def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(u_id=self.request.user)  => This works well :) Thank you very much

Comment: Fixes the typo !

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. sorry

Comment: I'll do it later

Comment: I am talking about "accepting answer", not upvoting :-)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Adopted the answer :)